# A question about S4 modal system

Tags: logic

I am reading Fitting and Mendelsohn's [first-order modal logic](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-011-5292-1). I have some questions about the $\textit{de re}$ and $\textit{de dicto}$ necessity. Assume that we are working with an S4 system, is $(\star)$ or $(\star\star)$ valid?

$$\Box(\exists xA(x)\rightarrow\exists yB(y))\rightarrow(\exists x\Box A(x)\rightarrow\exists y\Box B(y))\tag{$\star$}$$
$$(\exists xA(x)\rightarrow\exists yB(y))\rightarrow(\exists x\Box A(x)\rightarrow\exists y\Box B(y))\tag{$\star\star$}$$

$(\star)$ is quite similar to the distribution axiom for $\Box$, but in this case, there is a $\textit{de re}$/$\textit{de dicto}$ shift. I don't know how to verify or falsify it.

Comment: Should both occurrences of $B(x)$ be $B(y)$?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh yes, I have corrected it.